# ¿Cómo conecto power bi a workbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench, powerbi

Les pongo en situación, yo utilizo workbench para conectarme a la base de datos de la empresa donde trabajo, la conexión está hecha por medio de un túnel SSH (Standard TCP/IP over SSH), quiero utilizar para hacer visualizaciones, Power BI, cuando quiero hacer la conexión me pide:

Nombre del servidor
Base de datos
User
Password

Mis preguntas son, ¿cuál es el nombre del servidor que debo usar?
el de la conexión me manda un error,

y por otro lado, para esa conexión, como usé un SSH key file, no utilicé una contraseña,  ¿qué es lo que debo poner?.

No soy experto en conexiones, vaya, no soy experto ni en mysql, estoy empezando en ello, y ya he probado el nombre del servidor que viene en la conexión con Workbench y me manda error de "No es posible conectarse a la base de datos"
¿Alguien me podría ayudar?

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Un gusto saludarte, workbench aquí es solo es un gestor de DDBM por lo que deberías sacarlo por lo menos del concepto.

En powerBI debes hacer una conexión nueva de base de datos y el motor a seleccionar debe MySQL, los datos siguientes son :

host: IP donde está tu base de datos
Username : Con el que accedes a administrar la base
Password: Password que usas para tu usuario de administración de base de datos.

Aspectos a tener en cuenta: Debes tener acceso entre redes para que se vea la base de datos, si el powerBI digamos está en tu maquina y la base de datos está en una oficina asegúrate de poder alcanzar esta máquina.